# Oracle Active Data Guard: FSFO Observer

Tags: oracle

It is recommended by Oracle to use Observer (for fast start failover) in separate node to observe Primary/Standby nodes.

Could it be possible to use observer on Primary/Standby node? Otherwise a separate node will be required.

Comment: There is an update, Oracle12.2 has now have the feature to run multiple observer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to run observer process on Primary/Standby nodes. Then what happen when the standby or primary node goes down? The observer process also goes down with the primary site. If you run it on standby site it works only for one time, when standby become primary then the same problem arises.

So as recommended by Oracle it must be running on third site (separate node) from where it can observe both primary and standby site. When primary goes down it can initiate fail over process.

Comment: Thanks @JSapkota, yes I am now considering the observer on third machine.